# Records/Text not in SQL 'IN' clause

Tags: sql, sybase

What is the best to return a set (array?) of strings that are not found by the 'IN' clause. For e.g.

let's assume the FRUIT table only contains 'APPLE', 'PEACHES', 'KIWI' and 'BANANA'.
The query below will return 'APPLE' AND 'BANANA'

```
SELECT FRUIT_NAME 
FROM FRUIT 
WHERE FRUIT_NAME IN ('APPLE', 'BANANA', 'ORANGE', 'PEAR')
```

How do I return 'ORANGE' and 'PEAR', i.e., items that are not in the table, but are a part of my search criteria?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you want to return names whether they are in the table or not, why would you even need to look in the table? E.g. use the equivalent of this PostgreSQL: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('APPLE'), ('BANANA'), ('ORANGE'), ('PEAR')) AS FRUIT (FRUIT_NAME)`

Answer (score 0):

The general way is to do the `left join`

```
select t.*
from (select 'APPLE' as fruits union all
      select 'BANANA' union all
      select 'ORANGE' union all
      select 'PEAR') t left join FRUIT f
                     on t.fruits = f.fruits 
where t.fruits is null;
```